# From PHP array variables to Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Im new to Smarty and not sure how to convert following code in PHP to Smarty.

In PHP I have external file:

```
$meta['https://example.com/domainchecker.php']['title'] = "Domain Search";
$meta['https://example.com/domainchecker.php']['description'] = "Description etc";
$meta['https://example.com/domainchecker.php?search=bulk']['title'] = "Domain Search Bulk";
$meta['https://example.com/domainchecker.php?search=bulk']['description'] = "Description etc";
```

normally in PHP I could do this:

```
<?php include ("includes/metatags.php");?>

<?php if ($meta[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]['title']  != ''){?>
  <title> <?php echo$meta[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]['title'];?> </title>
  <meta name="description" content="<?php echo$meta[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]['description'];?>">
<?php}?>
```

I have tried this:

```
{php} include ("templates/flathost/includes/metatags.php");{/php}
{if $meta[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]['title']  neq ''}
<title>{php} echo$meta[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]['title'];{/php} </title>
<meta name="description" content="{php} echo$meta[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]['description'];{/php}">
{/if}
```

but is not working well...

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign your data to Smarty.

```
$smarty = new Smarty();

$smartyData = $smarty->createData();
$smartyData->assign( 'foo', 'bar' );

$tpl = $smarty->createTemplate( 'someTemplate.tpl', $smartyData );
$tpl->display();
```

in Smarty file "someTemplate.tpl" you can now access the variables

```
{$foo} {* display´s "bar" *}
```